# Elixir/Phoenix can't connect to cloud hosted Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

trying to get my first Phoenix app connected to Compose's Cloud Hosted Postgres DB and am unable to connect. I have verified that it is up and running. I get the following error:

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.178.0> terminating
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (postgres://*****@aws-us-east-1-portal.5.dblayer.com:16786/compose:5432): non-existing domain - :nx
domain
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:148: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
** (Mix) The database for HelloPhoenix.Repo couldn't be created: an exception was raised:
    ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (postgres://****@aws-us-east-1-portal.5.dblayer.com:16786/compose:5432): non-existing domain -
:nxdomain
        (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:148: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
        (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

These are my dependencies:

```
defp deps do
  [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
  {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
  {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
  {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
  {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
  {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
  {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
  {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}]
end
```

And my DB Config:

```
# Configure your database
config :hello_phoenix, HelloPhoenix.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "admin",
  password: "******",
  database: "compose",
  hostname: "postgres://admin:******@aws-us-east-1-portal.5.dblayer.com:16786/compose",
  pool_size: 10
```

And using this version of PostgresSQL : **PostgreSQL 9.4.10**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :-)  Y'all take care! -Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hostname` of your database is `aws-us-east-1-portal.5.dblayer.com`, not the whole `postgres://...`. Also, you need to specify the port since it's not the default PostgreSQL port. This should work:

```
config :hello_phoenix, HelloPhoenix.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "admin",
  password: "******",
  database: "compose",
  hostname: "aws-us-east-1-portal.5.dblayer.com",
  port: 16786,
  pool_size: 10
```

Answer (score 5):

Since it seems you have a full database URL, probably the easiest solution for you will be to use that URL and let ecto decode it into the constituent parts that it needs for connecting.

```
config :hello_phoenix, HelloPhoenix.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: "postgres://admin:******@aws-us-east-1-portal.5.dblayer.com:16786/compose",
  pool_size: 10
```

Here's the documentation for that feature: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#module-urls

Comment: thanks for the input! I had read Dogbert's solution before yours and tried it so that is why I marked his as "correct"; but just wanted to say thanks for responding and pointing me towards that feature in the documentation. :-)